# Add a parameter to a method with a Roslyn CodeFixProvider

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing a [Roslyn Code Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn879356) that I want to identify if an `async` method does *not* take a `CancellationToken` and then suggest a code fix that adds it:

```
 //Before Code Fix:
 public async Task Example(){}

 //After Code Fix
 public async Task Example(CancellationToken token){}
```

I've wired up the `DiagnosticAnalyzer` to correctly report a Diagnostic by inspecting the `methodDeclaration.ParameterList.Parameters`, but I can't find the Roslyn API for adding a `Paramater` to the `ParameterList` inside a `CodeFixProvider`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
private async Task<Document> HaveMethodTakeACancellationTokenParameter(
        Document document, SyntaxNode syntaxNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var method = syntaxNode as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

    // what goes here?
    // what I want to do is: 
    // method.ParameterList.Parameters.Add(
          new ParameterSyntax(typeof(CancellationToken));

    //somehow return the Document from method         
}
```

How do I correctly update the Method Declaration and return the updated `Document`?

Comment: I believe you have to replace the entire ParameterList, rather than adding a new parameter. It's been a while since I wrote analyzers!

Comment: `ParamaterList` has no setter :(.  Do I need to create a new MethodDeclaration from scratch?

Comment: I think so. If you want to throw this code up on github or something, I'd be happy to take a crack at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Nate Barbettini is correct, syntax nodes are all immutable, so I needed to create a new version of the `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, then replace the old method with the new method in the `document`'s `SyntaxTree`:

```
private async Task<Document> HaveMethodTakeACancellationTokenParameter(
        Document document, SyntaxNode syntaxNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var method = syntaxNode as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

        var updatedMethod = method.AddParameterListParameters(
            SyntaxFactory.Parameter(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("cancellationToken"))
                .WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof (CancellationToken).FullName)));

        var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync(cancellationToken);

        var updatedSyntaxTree = 
            syntaxTree.GetRoot().ReplaceNode(method, updatedMethod);

        return document.WithSyntaxRoot(updatedSyntaxTree);
    }
```